# how to use if in click listener for go different activity?

Tags: listview, android-intent, android-listview, android

I have search bar in the first page of my application , when I write to search bar open the search assist (list view for help) , I want to click each item of the list view to go to a different activity.

Problem : I don't know to use `if` in this list view for going to a different activity. I tested this code but just get to first activity in first `if`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> adp;
    // Array of strings storing country names
    String[] countries = new String[] {
            "India",
            "Pakistan",
            "Sri Lanka",
            "China",
            "Bangladesh",
            "Nepal",
            "Afghanistan",
            "North Korea",
            "South Korea",
            "Japan"
    };

 // Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
    int[] flags = new int[]{
                R.drawable.india,
                R.drawable.pakistan,
                R.drawable.srilanka,
                R.drawable.china,
                R.drawable.bangladesh,
                R.drawable.nepal,
                R.drawable.afghanistan,
                R.drawable.nkorea,
                R.drawable.skorea,
                R.drawable.japan
    };

    // Array of strings to store currencies
    String[] currency = new String[]{
        "Indian Rupee",
        "Pakistani Rupee",
        "Sri Lankan Rupee",
        "Renminbi",
        "Bangladeshi Taka",
        "Nepalese Rupee",
        "Afghani",
        "North Korean Won",
        "South Korean Won",
        "Japanese Yen"
    };




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
        List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();


        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
            hm.put("txt", countries[i]);
            hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );
            hm.put("cur", currency[i]);
            aList.add(hm);
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "flag","txt"};

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt};

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.autocomplete_layout, from, to);

        // Getting a reference to CustomAutoCompleteTextView of activity_main.xml layout file
        CustomAutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = ( CustomAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);

        /** Defining an itemclick event listener for the autocompletetextview */
        OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            if(parent.getAdapter().getItem(position).equals("India")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestPage.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if(parent.getAdapter().getItem(position).equals("Pakistan")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestPage2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }


            }
        };

        /** Setting the itemclick event listener */
        autoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

        /** Setting the adapter to the listView */
        autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    /** A callback method, which is executed when this activity is about to be killed
     * This is used to save the current state of the activity 
     * ( eg :  Configuration changes : portrait -> landscape )  
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        TextView tvCurrency = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_currency) ;       
        outState.putString("currency", tvCurrency.getText().toString());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    /** A callback method, which is executed when the activity is recreated 
     * ( eg :  Configuration changes : portrait -> landscape )  
     */
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView tvCurrency = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_currency) ;       
        tvCurrency.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("currency"));
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you click the listitem for Pakistan?

Comment: You should first check the return type of `getItem()`. Does it return the item that you *think* it returns?

Comment: how can I use getitem()  in my code ,  what do you mean exactly , sorry I am new at eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your listview, as you are using a custom adapter, i can see that in the hashmap, you are adding three things, so you should use the `contains` method in the `onItemClick` listener of listview

Your code is file.
Replace `equals` with `contains`

Comment: tested it , but don't work . after search item when click to item jump the app

Comment: First of all debug your application,.,or paste the full project somewhere. i will take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

custom listview will not support onitemclicklistner as you are using. it will be better if you call setonclicklistner inside the baseadapter for each row. that will work perfectly. pls try it and let me know if you need more help. thanks